# Baking a Follow Path acts weird

Tags: animation

Once again I come for the wisedome of this forum...

I am doing a 2D GP animation of a pencil writing a letter.

I made a stroke, converted it to curve, parented the pen to an empty and a follow path constrains on the empty for the curve...

I struggled but it is working fine now...

BUT baking is reacting weird, I do get the keyframes (visual keying) but the baked animation "springs" away from the curve..l It is still doing the motion but not over the curve...

I suspect a origin/offset thing but can't figure it out on my own...

I am using blender 2.91

Thanks!

Pyrrhon

Comment: Please attach your simplified blend file to see your setup. Use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and paste given code into your question.

Comment: Did you bake visuals?  Did you clear constraints?  If you did the first but not the second, you're double dipping on your follow path.  If you baked visuals, also clear constraints.